# Jcombobox and switch case

Tags: switch-statement, jcombobox

I want to link my combobox selected item with switch case which result in different result depend on option chosen. But return in this error :Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to java.awt.event.ItemListener. Can only one help me, thanks you so much!

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jComboBox1.addItemListener((ItemListener) jComboBox1);
    int usertype = (int) jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();

switch (usertype)   {
    case '1':
        new ResidentView().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        break;
    case '2':
        new OfficeClerkView().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        break;
    case '3':
        new OfficeManagerView().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        break;
}
```

Comment: casting error in this part, please check
jComboBox1.addItemListener((ItemListener) jComboBox1);

Comment: sorry, can you explain in more detail? thanks

Comment: jComboBox1 is not an ItemListener type, can u paste the definition for your combo box also?

Comment: thanks for fast respond. Here it is

Comment: jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Resident", "Office Clerk", "Office Manager" }));
        jComboBox1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

Comment: can u comment out this line?  jComboBox1.addItemListener((ItemListener) jComboBox1); check what happens

Comment: do you mean by delete that line?

Comment: comment it out will do